# Saving serialised sortable data from jQuery/ajax using Laravel 4+

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-4

Having an issue working out the best way to save an ajax sortable list into my database. I'm using [HTML5Sortable](https://github.com/voidberg/html5sortable) and Laravel 4.2 framework. The basic end result I'm trying to achieve is for a user to be able to click and drag the list items and reorder them and this new order will be saved in the database in a field called "order" so that when they return to the page later the new order will be present.

I have a list of chapters on the page like so:

```
<ul class="sortable">
    @foreach ($chapters as $chapter)
      <li class="ui-state-default" data-order="{{ $chapter->order }}">{{ $chapter->title }}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

And I can drag and drop sort these using HTML5Sortable and then serialize this data and submit it via ajax POST, which fires off each time the list is reordered like so:

```
$('.sortable').sortable().bind('sortupdate', function(e, ui) {

    var order = $('ul.sortable li').map(function(){ 
        return $(this).data("order");
    }).get();

    var uuid = "<?php echo$uuid; ?>";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "api-ch-order",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {order: order, uuid: uuid},
        success: function(order){
          console.log(order)
        }
    });
});
```

My controller at /api-ch-order gets the data and **saves** the new order like so:

```
if(Request::ajax()){

  $uuid = Input::get('uuid');
  $order = Input::get('order');

  $i = 1;

  foreach($order as $position) {

    $chapter = Chapter::where('book_uuid', $uuid)->where('order', $position)->first();

    $chapter->order = $i;
    $chapter->save();

    $i++;

  }

}
```

**THE PROBLEM**

The issue I'm having with this approach is that it wont work in some circumstances, the loop causes problems.

e.g.

LOOP 1: FIND Chapter where order = 2 and change order to 1

LOOP 2: FIND Chapter where order = 1 and change it to 2

The problem here is that in LOOP 2 it is finding result of LOOP 1 and updating this instead... I think... This problem is confusing me quite a bit... But I'm 99% sure the foreach loop in my controller is the problem and I'm not sure the best approach to fix this.

Resources to link to this question:

- [How To Use Jquery UI Sortable in Laravel 4](http://michaelbrooks.co.uk/post/how-to-use-jquery-ui-sortable-in-laravel-4)
- [Serialize data for AJAX using HTML5sortable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591533/serialize-data-for-ajax-using-html5sortable)

**THE ANSWER!!!**

As r4xz mentioned, the answer is to use ID as the constant.

E.g.

HTML

```
<ul class="sortable">
    @foreach ($chapters as $chapter)
      <li class="ui-state-default" data-id="{{ $chapter->id }}">{{ $chapter->title }}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

JS

```
$('.sortable').sortable().bind('sortupdate', function(e, ui) {

    var id = $('ul.sortable li').map(function(){ 
        return $(this).data("id");
    }).get();

    var uuid = "<?php echo$uuid; ?>";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "api-ch-order",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {id: id, uuid: uuid},
        success: function(order){
          console.log(id)
        }
    });
});
```

PHP CONTROLLER

```
if(Request::ajax()){

  $uuid = Input::get('uuid');
  $id = Input::get('id');

  $i = 1;

  foreach($id as $val) {

    $chapter = Chapter::where('id', $val)->first();

    $chapter->order = $i;
    $chapter->save();

    $i++;

  }

}
```

Comment: I love the examples you give here. I have finally gotten the sortable list to sort, but it doesn't appear to be posting... I can't figure out what's going on. Got any ideas?

Comment: You use $.ajax in your JS (like above) and post it to a route in your routes.php file e.g. Route::post('api-ch-order', 'SomeController@SomeFunction'); then use what I have above for the controller. That should work...

Comment: If still no luck after this then post up a new question and link it to me here and I'll see if I can help :)

Comment: Thank you. I'm pretty sure I have my route correct. If it were wrong then I should get an error from Laravel saying the route is wrong, correct? I get those errors often enough that I would know how to fix the problem if I saw the error. Anyway, here is the link to my post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26280943/html5sortable-with-laravel-will-not-submit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common solution is to save position and entity id:

```
<li data-id="{{ $chapter->id }}" data-order="{{ $chapter->order }}">{{ $chapter->title }}</li>
```

Then in controller you simply use:

```
UPDATE chapter SET order = $order WHERE id = $id
```

Comment: Perfect. That's exactly what I ended up going with! Will post full answer as an edit to my question.

Answer (score 0):

This question was very helpfull and gives a selfanswer into it ! GREAT ! Thanks !

Just for those in my case not using the same structure.
This is what I did :

```
public function myRouteFunction(Request $request)
    foreach($ids as $key => $id) {
        $update = DB::table('mybase')->where('id', $id)->update(['sort_order' => $key]);
    }
}
```

Maybe this could help someone :)