# jQuery UI Sortable with Laravel will not submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-4

After a lot of trial and error I finally got a sortable list to allow you to drag and drop to resort, but I cannot get the list to save.

My guess is that it is an issue with the JS portion of the code, because from what it looks like, the controller never gets called. And if I had something wrong with how I called the controller but it still attempted then Laravel would throw an error.

The answer is probably really simple, but I don't know much about Jquery or Ajax so I couldn't spot the problem.

Here is my code:

**View**

```
    <ul class="sortable" style="list-style-type: none;">
@foreach ($departments as $department)
    <li class="row" id="{{ $department->id }}">
        <div class="col-xs-9"><span style="color: {{ $department->color }};">{{ $department->name }}</span></div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <a href="{{ URL::route('chapter.editDepartment', (array($chapter->slug, $department->id))) }}"> EDIT </a>
        </div>
    </li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

**JS**
After using "view source" I can see that the URL did generate correctly, so that should be good.

```
    <script>

    $('.sortable').sortable().bind('sortupdate', function(e, ui) {

        var order = $('ul.sortable li').map(function(){
            return $(this).data("id");
        }).get();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{{ URL::route('chapter.departmentSort', $chapter->slug) }}",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {order: order, uuid: uuid},
            success: function(order){
                console.log(order)
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

**Controller**

```
public function departmentSort($chapterSlug)
{
    // Get the chapter ID
    $chapter = $this->getChapterFromSlug($chapterSlug);

    $input = Input::get('order');
    $i = 1;

    foreach($input as $value) {
        $department = Department::find($value);

        $department->sort_order = $i;

        $department->save();

        $i++;
    }

    return Redirect::route('chapter.chapterDepartments', $chapter->slug);
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::post('{slug}/orderDepartment', ['as' => 'chapter.departmentSort', 'uses' => 'SerenityController@departmentSort']);
```

**ANSWER**

Thanks to Josh I was able to understand this, and with just a little more searching I got it to work! The $.ajax didn't work, and the console showed nothing for that, but I swapped it out for $.post and it works like a champ.

```
$.post("{{ URL::route('chapter.departmentSort', $chapter->slug) }}", { order: order } );
```

Now the only problem is that the drag & drop doesn't work on ipad...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's a few things wrong with your code I can see here - I'll try my best to set you on the right path:

Firstly in your view your li tag needs to have a data-order="" attribute containing the department id e.g.

```
<li data-id="{{ $department->id }}">{{ $department->name }}</li>
```

This is so your JS can get and use this data at:

```
return $(this).data("id");
```

Secondly where your JS says:

```
data: {order: order, uuid: uuid},
```

You don't have a uuid so you don't need to submit one, you only need to submit the order like so:

```
data: {order: order},
```

And finally I would suggest you use the Google Chrome Javascript console to debug your javascript. It has good error reporting - just press Option+CMD+J on a Mac (I assume the Windows equivalent is Alt+Ctrl+J)

Comment: Thank you so much! You got me on the right track and it saves now! BUT, for some reason on ipad and iphone it doesn't let me drag and drop. It used to... Any ideas on how to troubleshoot that?

Comment: Hey, ahh yeah - HTML5Sortable (which you are using) does not have mobile support and wont work with mobile. See this comment from the author of HTML5Sortable suggesting you use jQuery UI with Touch Punch: https://github.com/farhadi/html5sortable/issues/1

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into that for my next update. I don't think my users need mobile support for this right now, and it's after 10:30, so I'm going to wrap this up and go to bed. :D Thanks for the help.